# php, get some code from text

Tags: php

how from this text get WORD and WORD2.

```
text tex asad t text [mycode]WORD[/mycode] tex asda [mycode]WORD2[/mycode] asdasdasd
```

I try using preg-match, but i fail

Comment: Artefacto means: post the code that failed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$str = "text tex asad t text [mycode]WORD[/mycode] tex asda [mycode]WORD2[/mycode] asdasdasd";
preg_match_all("/\[mycode\](.*?)\[\/mycode\]/", $str, $preg);
print_r($preg);
```

Comment: I don't know why everyone is so insistent on starting and ending their regexes with a forward slash..... you wouldn't have to escape it if you used something different!